# Get the upper right corner location of MessageBox in C++?

Tags: c++, position, messagebox

I basically want to get the location of a MessageBox's top right corner (Where it's red x button is located on the screen), but I don't know how. I don't want to change its position/location, but only get it.

Please help!

(using the windows.h header)

Comment: What kind of MessageBox? What Library are you working with? MFC?

Comment: Are you searching the position inside the MessageBox or on your screen?

Comment: On my screen I guess? I want to play around with windows.h and make a silly program where it measures the distance of the mouse cursor from red X button on the message box.